# How to realloc properly?

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I wrote a little function to return a string made from the input given to the program, it worked fine until i traded constant size for dynamic memory allocation.
 After i tested with a few printf() it looks like the program crashes when realloc() is called.
 **Am i doing something wrong with realloc(), or is it something else?**

```
char* get_line()
{
    size_t ptr_pos = 0, size = 50;
    int c;
    char* line = malloc(size * sizeof *line);
    char* temp;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(++ptr_pos >= size)
        {
            size += 50;
            temp = realloc(line, size * sizeof *line); // The program crashes on this intruction.

            if(temp != NULL)
            {
                line = temp;
                printf("Reallocation success.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Reallocation error.\n");
                free(line);
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        *line++ = c;
        if(c == '\n')
            break;
    }
    if(ptr_pos == 0)
        return NULL;
    *line = '\0';

    return line - ptr_pos;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `malloc()` and `realloc()` return `void *`. You are using them directly as `char *`. Convert them explicitly.

Comment: You might like to replace `*line++ = c;` by `line[ptr_pos - 1] = c;`.

Comment: @Pawan: This is *not* necessary, nor recommend in C. C is not C++.

Comment: @Pawan [c - Do I cast the result of malloc? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) - no.

Comment: @alk "You might like to replace `*line++ = c;` by `line[ptr_pos - 1] = c;`" . Now that i have read rici's answer i understand why this will suppress the mistake, good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `realloc`, you must give it the address of the beginning of the allocated memory, the same address as was originally returned by `malloc`. The same is true of `free`.

But you are modifying the value of `line`, so it is no longer pointing to the beginning of the block when `realloc` is called.

That is Undefined Behaviour, so a segfault is definitely possible.